# Was able to write in bucket after mounting the bucket into Laravel public folder (using gcsfuse), but unable to read

Tags: laravel, google-cloud-platform, gcsfuse

So I am currently working on an API app, and I am trying to mount the bucket into my Laravel app inside public folder. It all went well,

[image: I could open the mounted bucket and see all the files through ssh.]

and I even managed to write into the disk, but it's very weird that I couldn't open the file through URL (e.g. localhost:8000/mountedimgdir/img.png) despite I could open other files inside public dir through the same means.

I tried doing chmod and some other suggestion from other threads, but the problem still persists.

Comment: What's the permissions?

Comment: I tried to change the permission for the bucket to public access, which didn't work

Comment: Could you please share the error message that you're seeing?

Comment: @SathiAiswarya unfortunately there is no error message regarding of the mountings, it just goes 404 whenever I tried to access the image through website (e.g. https://link.com/mountedimgdir/img.png) while if you can still access them without problem through ssl

Comment: Are you sure you mount correctly the bucket?

Comment: okay, so my team managed to resolve the problem, from what he said, he didn't really explain too much, but it has something to do with "not using it with root user, and making the mounted bucket into an implicit directory", therefore Google prevented the folder to be accessed through web, I'll try to get the full explanation for the resolve, but so far, that's what I got

Comment: Can you please clarify the following things?

***A***. You can not open the file through the URL which is written by you, or all the files belong to the mounted bucket?
***B*** What is the exact error you are facing?
***C*** Can you please share the whole log file with --debug_gcs, --debug_fs, --debug_fuse, --log_format text, --log-file ~/log.log flags enabled to debug it more?